# Split string using space and capital letter

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split my string into multiple rows. String looks like this:

```
x <- c("C 10.1 C 12.4","C 12", "C 45.5 C 10")
```

Code snippet:

```
strsplit(x, "//s")[[3]]
```

Result:

```
"C 45.5 C 10"
```

Expected Output: Split string into multiple rows like this:

```
"C 10.1"
"C 12.4"
"C 12"
"C 45.5"
"C 10"
```

The question is how to split the string?

Clue: there is a space and then character which is "C" in our case. Anyone who knows how to do it?

Comment: What is your expected output?  It is a bit strange mentioning rows in the context of a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=C)", perl=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
[1] "C 10.1" "C 12.4" "C 12"   "C 45.5" "C 10"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/9FaYWD) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJ2X28/2).

The `(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=C)` regex matches 1 or more whitespace characters (`\\s+`) that are immediately preceded with a digit (`(?<=\\d)`) and that are immediately followed with `C`.

If `C` can be any uppercase ASCII letter, replace `C` with `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 1):

A somwhat more complicated expression but easier on the regex side:

```
unlist(
  sapply(
    strsplit(x, " ?C"),
    function(x) {
      paste0("C", x[nzchar(x)])
    }
  )
)
"C 10.1" "C 12.4" "C 12"   "C 45.5" "C 10"
```

Comment: Interesting. You may also change `?` to `*` to match any 0+ spaces, or even `\\s*` to match any 0+ whitespace chars.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder which would be considered best practice. Look forward to learn more about regex.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [*Mastering Quantifiers*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html). Note that in human-written texts, whitespaces might be any, and they may be missing, there are typos, etc. So it is a good idea to use `\s*` to make sure we match 0, 1, 2, etc. whitespaces. Since hard and soft whitespace may occur, it might be even a better idea to use `[[:space:]]` POSIX character class or use `(*UCP)\s` with a PCRE regex (`perl=TRUE`).